# Download pages that I have to log in to get with wget

Tags: linux, login, wget, authentication

There's a website that I must log in to before I can browse the content, and the content would be very helpful for my work if I could browse it while offline. It's training and repair information for quite a few things.

I could us wget to get the pages, but I have no idea how I'd log in to be able to get the pages, or if wget would even work.

Anyone have any ideas if it's possible to authenticate with wget to download pages?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication